# How can I print whole data of a packet in c?

Tags: c, networking, libpcap

I'm using `libpcap` in `c` to write a packet sniffer. How can I print whole data in the packet?
I'v tried this way:

```c
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>


void packet_process(u_char *args,const struct pcap_pkthdr *header,const u_char *packet){

        struct ether_header *eh;
        const u_char *ip_header;
        ip_header = packet + 14;
        u_char proto = *(ip_header+9);
        eh=(struct ether_header *) packet;
        const u_char *ptr = packet;
        int bytes = 0;
        char packet_content[1000];
        static int i=0;
        fprintf(stdout, "%d) len: %d\n", ++i, header->len);
        while(bytes ++ < 1000){
                packet_content[bytes-1] = *ptr;
                ptr ++;
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n\n", packet_content);
        fflush(stdout);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char error[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t *handle = pcap_open_live(argv[1], BUFSIZ, 0, -2, error);
    pcap_loop(handle, atoi(argv[2]),packet_process, NULL );
    pcap_close(handle);
    return 0;

}
```

but this code does not show whole data in packet, the output of this code was this:

```
[amirreza@localhost tmp]$ sudo ./a.out enp3s0 5
1) len: 118
0���:T����

2) len: 145
T����0���:

3) len: 118
0���:T����

4) len: 145
T����0���:

5) len: 117
0���:T����
```

I don't know how make them human readable and also print whole data in the packet.

Comment: Something like `for (int j = 0; j < header->len; j++) printf("%02X ", ptr[j]);`? What printing format do you want?

Comment: @MikeCAT I want to print packet in ASCII.

Comment: To do that, you have to know exactly which bytes in the packet are in fact ASCII data.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker how can I find this? my purpose of seeing packet data is distinguish type of dns packets. but I don't know how to find dns packets.

Comment: DNS packets are on port 53.

Comment: @stark it's default port, but it's possible that some other packets go through this port.

Answer (score 3):

At least these issues

**Printing array as *string* without a *null chracter***

Append a *null chracter* or limit printing.

**Printing unassigned elements of an array**

Limit printing

**Assigning outside array bounds**

Limit assignment loop.

```
    char packet_content[1000];
    static int i=0;
    fprintf(stdout, "%d) len: %d\n", ++i, header->len);
    int limit = header->len < 1000 ? header->len : 1000;  // add
    //while(bytes ++ < 1000){
    while(bytes ++ < limit){
            packet_content[bytes-1] = *ptr;
            ptr ++;
    }
    // fprintf(stdout, "%s\n\n", packet_content);
    fprintf(stdout, "%.*s\n\n", limit, packet_content);
```

---

To print data as hexadecimal

```
    // fprintf(stdout, "%s\n\n", packet_content);
    for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) {
      fprintf(stdout, " %02X", (unsigned char) packet_content[i]);
      // or since C99
      fprintf(stdout, " %02hhX", packet_content[i]);
      // or best, use unsigned packet_content[1000]
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "\n\n");
```

To print data as in mixed ASCII and hexadecimal

```
    for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) {
      unsigned char ch = packet_content[i];
      if (isprint(ch)) {
        fprintf(stdout, " '%c", ch);
      } else {
        fprintf(stdout, " %02X", ch);
      }
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
```

Comment: thanks but the result of this code is as same as my own. maybe you can help me if I explain my real purpose. I need to find all dns packets. and I want to print it's data to find a solution. but if there will be an easier way to find them I'm thanks to explain me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have pcap here to test it, but i'd start from something really simple, just dump the entire packets, without parsing them, after this part works, proceed with filtering, parsing, etc. Something like this:

```
void dump(const void* voidbuf, int len)
{
    static int linecnt = 16;
    const unsigned char* buf = voidbuf;
    for (int i=0; i<len; i+=linecnt, putch('\n'))
    {
        for (int j=0; j<linecnt; j++, putch(' '))
        {
            static const char HEX[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
            putch(i+j<len ? HEX[buf[i+j] >> 4] : ' ');
            putch(i+j<len ? HEX[buf[i+j] & 0x0F] : ' ');
        }
        putch('|');
        putch(' ');
        for (int j=0; j<linecnt; j++)
            putch(i+j<len ? (buf[i+j]>=' ' && buf[i+j]<='z' ? buf[i+j] : '.') : ' ');
    }
}

// libpcap callback
void packet_process(u_char *args,const struct pcap_pkthdr *header,const u_char *packet)
{
    // just dump the entire thing, after you see this working properly, start working 
    // on filtering just the packets you want, and then, finally, fully parsing the 
    // packets that are out of intereset
    dump(packet, header->caplen);
}
```